# Validação de Javascript com jQuery Mask

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masked-input

Estou desenvolvendo uma área onde o aluno se cadastrará nela, portanto resolvi buscar ajuda de bibliotecas como o jQuery, obtive um bom resultado diante disso, porém está ocorrendo alguns erros no meu script que não consigo identificar.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="dados" id="dados" method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="cpf" name="cpf" placeholder="CPF">
  <input type="text" id="telefone" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone">
  <input type="text" id="celular" name="celular" placeholder="Celular">
</form>
</body>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
             $('#cep').mask('00000-000');
             $('#telefone').mask('0000-0000');
             $('#celular').mask('00000-0000');
             $('#cpf').mask('000.000.000-00', {reverse: true});
             $('#rg').mask('00.000.000-00', {reverse: true});
        });
      </script>
```

Este jQuery Mask é desenvolvido por: https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html

**OBS: Meu script não funciona a aplicação de mascaras citadas anteriormente.**

Comment: Você precisa adicionar o jquery no head também, não só o plugin do masked input.

Comment: Eu o adicionei agora <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> porém não funciona.

Comment: Só pra deixar claro o link do jQuer deve vir primeiro que o link do plugin vc sabe né? Tipo  assim: <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.js"></script>

Comment: Sim, eu fiz assim.

Comment: tente inserir via cdn o jquery. `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Agradeço pela ajuda, mas continua não rodando meu script... Não sei o que está de errado sinceramente.

Comment: Sempre quando for trabalhar com Javascript deixe o console do navegador aberto. Aperte **f12** se estiver utilizando o **Chrome** e veja se está dando algum erro na aba **console**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui funcionou, assim:

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="dados" id="dados" method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="cpf" name="cpf" placeholder="CPF">
  <input type="text" id="telefone" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone">
  <input type="text" id="celular" name="celular" placeholder="Celular">
</form>
</body>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
             $('#cep').mask('00000-000');
             $('#telefone').mask('0000-0000');
             $('#celular').mask('00000-0000');
             $('#cpf').mask('000.000.000-00', {reverse: true});
             $('#rg').mask('00.000.000-00', {reverse: true});
        });
      </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Pelo o que eu observei, seu código está igual o meu correto?

Comment: Sim... apenas coloquei o </html> no final, e adicionei o script do jquery ao <haed>